# Javascript/Safari - Searching a webpage's text using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, safari, innerhtml, safari-extension

I'm working on an extension for Mac OS X's Safari browser. I only want this extension to execute if a few specific strings appear on the page. It should search for these strings throughout the entire HTML document.

Validation bool:

```
function validateStringsPresent(){
    var index1 = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf(validationText1);
    var index2 = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf(validationText2);

    /* For testing purposes only */
    alert("If an index = -1, it is not on the page" + "\n" + "\n"
            + index1 + "\n" + "\n"
            + index2);

    if (index1 != -1 && index2 != -1) {return true};
    else {return false};
}
```

As you've guessed, I get `-1` for both indexes on a page that *does* contain the Validation Text. There are no special characters in these strings except for `:`, but that shouldn't be a factor.

My theory is that I need something other than the `document` class when using an extension in Safari. To get the current URL, for example, the `document` class didn't work either. I had to use `var currentUrl = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;`

I haven't been able to find the correct Safari Class to accomplish what I am trying to do, though.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

Now trying via injected script.

Button click function:

```
function performCommand(event)
{
    getHTML();
}

safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, true);
```

injected.js:
function getHTML()

```
{
    var val1 = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

    alert("You are using injected.js" + "\n" + "\n"
            + val1);    
}
```

As you can see in the screen shots below, getHTML() is returning the HTML from my global file and not the current web page.

[image: Alert]

[image: Extension Builder]

Comment: Where did you put this code? In the [global page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage.html) or in an [injected script](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html)?

Comment: It is in the global page and I am using a button in the toolbar to activate my extension

Comment: You need an injected script, and pass around a message, see https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html.

Comment: Thanks, I am now injecting my .js file, but it is returning HTML from my global page and not the active window/tab

Comment: Then you're *not* injecting HTML. FYI, "Injected script" in Safari extensions is similar to "content script" in Chrome/Firefox extensions: Scripts that run in the context of a tab instead of the extension's background page. The global page is an invisible page that runs in the background.

Comment: Do I need to build and install my extension rather than using the standard testing process? I have the .js set as an end script. I have no idea why it is grabbing my global.html file

Comment: I have no idea how you're running your code, so I can't comment on that unless you provide more relevant information.

Comment: Additional details added.

Comment: Read the manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html